# Is there a way to unit test ASP.NET MVC ViewBag properties set in the view?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

Say I have a view with the following code at the top of the page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

And I have a controller method:

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

How can I test that the ViewBag was set properly?

I have tried the following code.

```
[TestCase]
public void About()
{
    var controller = new AboutController();
    var ar = controller.About() as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("About Us", ar.ViewBag.Title);
}
```

But I get the following result when I run the test:

```
Tests.Controllers.AboutControllerTests.About():
    Expected: "About Us"
    But was: null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot test views like this. The closest you might get is to render the view into a stream writer and then test the generated HTML. It is not something that is commonly done in unit tests. I would recommend you performing web tests in order to verify that the views are correct. You could create web tests with [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182538%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or there's also the free [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) framework.

Comment: I also use the stream writer/reader approach @Darin suggested.

Comment: Anyone viewing this and giving up on solving the problem, scroll down to @phil.wheeler's answer, it helped me! `ViewData[yourKey]` or `ViewData["Title"]` NB, this works if you set the `Viewbag.Title` value in the controller, not in the `cshtml`

Comment: A wrong answer is given later than the correct answer and the asker chose the wrong answer?

Answer (score 59):

Since both the ViewData and ViewBag use the same storage pattern, you should be able to use `ViewData[yourKey]` in your tests.

So your test will look like this:

```
[TestCase]
public void About()
{
    var controller = new AboutController();
    var ar = controller.About() as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("About Us", ar.ViewData["Title"]);
}
```

Comment: This method appears to work, but only if you are setting `ViewBag` values in the controller

Comment: I also found that you can reference ViewBag.Thing directly after casting result to ViewResult, e.g.
```var result = ctor.About() as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewBag.Message, "Your application description page.");```

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried

```
Assert.AreEqual("About Us", controller.ViewBag.Title);
```

It works for me

Comment: It does work, but is that the right way to assert that the view has got it?

Comment: Nope, it isn't...if the view throws an error on loading, you wouldn't know it by just testing the controller's title.

Answer (score 7):

The ViewResult returned by a controller has only a reference to the view that should be shown. The view is not even resolved at this time. The code there is never executed by your test.

What you should do is set ViewBag properties in the controller, not the view. Usually, the view will only read such values.

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth, I found that the following worked fine:

```
Assert.AreEqual(_layout, result.ViewBag.Layout);
```

With `result` being the `ViewResult`

Answer (score 2):

[TestMethod]

```
 public async Task GetData() {
    CtrlNameController controller = new CtrlNameController();

    controller.ViewData["UserId"] = 1;

    ViewResult result = await controller.GetData() as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

`ViewData["UserId"]` is equal to `View.UserId`